# What does this line from Stephen King "On Writing" mean?

Tags: meaning, stephen-king, on-writing

I'm confused about the bolded part:

> We went on a bus, about forty kids and three chaperones, and spent the first night in New York, where the drinking age was then eighteen. **Thanks to my bad ears and crappy tonsils, I was almost nineteen.** Room to spare.

What is the relevance of "bad ears" and "crappy tonsils" with respect to his age?

Comment: As a child, he spent a lot of time in hospital having his ears pinned back and tonsils removed, The implication being this caused him to drop back a year at school, so he was [nearly] a year older than his peer group. It doesn't make much sense to me, and I *did* spend the equivalent of nearly a year of my childhood in hospital having repeated plastic surgery. But the only reason ***I*** was younger than almost all of my classmates was because I was born in August, just the wrong side of the "cut-off" date for school year groups.

Comment: @FumbleFingers. Are those hospital stays covered in previous chapters of "On Writing"?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Did they send you class work in hospital so you could keep up? Sounds like King was unable to keep up.

Comment: @Barmar: Mostly I just lost 2-3 weeks of the summer holidays each year. They did have a "school" in the hospital though, and one year I was forced to learn how to write left-handed because they were doing skin-grafts from my right arm. (But I've gotten so used to keyboards now that I can barely do anything more complicated than "make my mark" (a scribbled signature) with a pen and paper! :)

Comment: @istillneedahero I think FumbleFingers's answer is reasonable, but I'd still like to know if that information (hospital stays) is somewhere in On Writing. Or is it just background information that King expected fans to know? I would interpret "Bad ears" as hearing problems, which might well prevent one from progressing in school.

Comment: @alphabet I think the answer is less important than how it was derived. Did FF have previous knowledge of King's "bad ears," or was it due to his own childhood experience? Upon first reading the OP, I thought the sentence meant being held back a year in school, but it wouldn't have occurred to me that "bad ears" had anything to do with ears that had to be pinned back. Is there a clue in the parallel colloquial adjectives?

Comment: @Zan700: I made the assumption precisely *because* of my own experience - where very noticeably, most other children were having ears pinned or tonsils snipped. But who knows? Perhaps my interpretation is spurious, and he meant he missed a lot of school because of persistent tonsillitis and poor hearing and/or susceptibility to ear infections.

Comment: Concerning the English alone - *For medical reasons, I was not only 18 and allowed to drink, but well over 18.*

Comment: King suffered from ear and throat infections when he was young. He sat out most of first grade and repeated it the following year. Hence he was a year older than his classmates. When he went on a high school trip, he was 19, well over the of legal drinking age of 18 in New York. (All of this is sourced from the actual book.)

Comment: My comment was mostly meant to clear up speculations in the comments. But the OP’s confusion is understandable, and the question has the makings of one that would be interesting. I can’t think of the terminology at the moment, but it’s along the lines of pseudo-conditional or pseudo-causal. *If you’re hungry, there’s a snack in the fridge.* *Since you asked, I am hungry.* *You are hungry because your stomach is growling.* ... *Because my ears were bad, I was nineteen.*...

Answer (score 4):

### [Show, don't tell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Show,_don%27t_tell)

King is using [subtext](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtext) to [infer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inference) the connection between his "bad ears and crappy tonsils" and the fact that he was considerably older than his classmates. We need to use [inductive reasoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductive_reasoning), so our conclusions can't be certain, but my reasoning goes something like this:

**Known Facts**

- King has "bad ears and crappy tonsils",
- He "was almost nineteen",
- The former is the cause of the latter,
- Being almost nineteen is [unusual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelfth_grade#:%7E:text=United%20States,-A%2012th%20grade&text=The%20twelfth%20grade%20is%20the%20twelfth%20school%20year%20after%20kindergarten,can%20be%2019%20years%20old.) for an American high school student - this is not something King tells us, but most of his readers would know this.

**Reasoning**

- if he is older than the normal age for students in his year, he started school at an older age, repeated one or more years of school or both.
- Either of these could be the result of developmental disruption caused by, say, chronic sickness,
- "bad ears and crappy tonsils" are the types of things that can cause chronic sickness. They may be aspects of the same underlying problem - there's a whole medical speciality, [otorhinolaryngology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otorhinolaryngology), dedicated to the ears, nose and throat (which is where the tonsils are).

**Conclusion**

King's "bad ears and crappy tonsils" caused sufficient illness that they delayed his normal progression into or through the education system, making him older than expected for a final-year high school student.

Comment: Bad ears and infected tonsils never cause ageing. Rather, with ageing come deteriorations leading to increased likelihood of disease. // Isn't King saying that effects of tonsillitis, and early-onset partial deafness, give a false impression of age?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth no he’s saying he was sick and missed enough school to be held back. That makes him older than his peers.

Comment: Right, that makes sense, though the way it's expressed gives the illnesses as the reason for his age while they constitute the reason why he's in an unexpected class for his age. Very unusual use of language.